# Invalid JSON response - DataTables Warning

Tags: php, sql, datatables

> DataTables warning: table id=mitabla - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Hola estoy siguiendo unos tutoriales de Youtube de PHP pero es del 2017 y por lo tanto me surgen bastantes errores. Este es uno con el que ya estoy trabado hace un día y no consigo solucionar, anteriormente tenia un problema en una linea de código SQL y pensé que era eso pero ahora lo resolví y el problema persiste.

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpASO9tL1gs&ab_channel=CódigosdeProgramación-MR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpASO9tL1gs&ab_channel=C%C3%B3digosdeProgramaci%C3%B3n-MR)

Este es el tutorial y video en concreto donde hace este cambio al dataTables.

```php
<?php
/*
    * Script:    Tablas de multiples datos del lado del servidor para PHP y MySQL
    * Copyright: 2016 - Marko Robles
    * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
*/

require 'conexion.php';

/* Nombre de La Tabla */
$sTabla = "personas";

/* Array que contiene los nombres de las columnas de la tabla*/
$aColumnas = array( 'id', 'nombre', 'correo', 'telefono' );

/* columna indexada */
$sIndexColumn = "id";

// Paginacion
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".$_GET['iDisplayStart'].", ".$_GET['iDisplayLength'];
}


//Ordenacion
if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
{
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
        {
            $sOrder .= $aColumnas[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
            ".$_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] .", ";
        }
    }
    
    $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
    if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
    {
        $sOrder = "";
    }
}

//Filtracion
$sWhere = "";
if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
    {
        $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

// Filtrado de columna individual 
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch_'.$i]."%' ";
    }
}


//Obtener datos para mostrar SQL queries
$sQuery = "
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumnas))."
FROM   $sTabla
$sWhere
$sOrder
$sLimit
";
$rResult = $mysqli->query($sQuery);

/* Data set length after filtering */
$sQuery = "
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
";
$rResultFilterTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
$aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_array();
$iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

/* Total data set length */
$sQuery = "
SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
FROM   $sTabla
";
$rResultTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
$aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch_array();
$iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];

/*
    * Output
*/
$output = array(
"sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
"iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
"iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
"aaData" => array()
);

while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch_array())
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumnas[$i] == "version" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumnas[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ];
        }
    }
    
    $row[] = "<td><a href='modificar.php?id=".$aRow['id']."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a></td>";
    $row[] = "<td><a href='#' data-href='eliminar.php?id=".$aRow['id']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></td>";
    
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

Este es el código del archivo server_process.php que es el que entiendo me genera este error. Por lo que entiendo el error podría estar quizás en sintaxis del json_encode() o quizás en la definición de las variables. Cualquier ayuda me sirve, muchas gracias de antemano.

El código original incluía SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS y FOUND_ROWS en las líneas 80 y 90 respectivamente pero los reemplace por Count ya que el primero mencionado esta desactualizado y se lo va a eliminar en versiones futuras de PHP.